# GWT, BigDecimal and RPC always returns 0

Tags: gwt, bigdecimal, gwt-rpc

I'm having a lot of troubles with creating a BigDecimal object on the client side and send it to the server via RPC. When I read the toString or toPlainString method of BigDecimal on the server side, it always returns 0. On the client side, the toPlainString methods returns the correct value, but toString still returns 0.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("1.2345");
GWT.log("Test: " + d.toString()); // 0
GWT.log("Test: " + d.toPlainString()); // 1.2345, OK!
```

As far as I can see, the BigDecimal should be supported, but I have not been able to create one on the client side and send to the server side successfully. (Reading them from server side, is no problem as long as I use the toPlainString method.)

Any suggestions? Thanks

EDIT: or asked in another way: has anyone been able to construct a BigDecimal on the client and send it to the server successfully?

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.7 and Java 1.8 on Mac OS 10.10.2, btw

Answer (score 0):

For me, this code:

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1.2345);
    System.out.println(bd.toString());
    System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

has the following output on both the server and client:

1.2344999999999999307220832633902318775653839111328125
1.2344999999999999307220832633902318775653839111328125

I'm using GWT 2.6 and Java 1.7, so maybe Java 1.8's implementation changed and it isn't fully emulated yet?  Also, make sure that the BigDecimal you're using is actually from java.math.